# "" is a type, which is not valid in the given context (.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I just created a .NET Core project with the MVC view. I created a CupModel in the models folder, and I am trying to use a foreach statement inside of the index view to display my model objects.

In my foreach statement, "CupModel" is underlined with the following message.

"CupModel" is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

I'm using this statement is at the top of my page.

```
@model IEnumerable<UserValidation.Models.CupModel>
```

My for each statement looks like this.

```
@foreach (var item in CupModel) {
<div>.......</div>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
```

Because `CupModel` is actually a type, and `Model` is your model's instance in that view context.

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" 

I am using @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.houseTitle) to access the object.

Comment: @nate that is another problem.. `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.houseTitle)` there you go

Comment: "IEnumerable cupModel does not contain a definition for houseTitle and no accessible extension method.......are you missing a directive or assembly reference?"

Comment: @nate dude, your whole view seems to be messed up. You should try a tutorial or something like that in the framework.

Comment: that's fair. thanks

Comment: Using `IEnumerable<anything>` as your model type is generally a bad idea. Tutorials do it to avoid extra classes but they shouldn't. Declare a class with a name based on the action, e.g. `IndexViewModel` for the `Index` action method) and add properties to it, e.g. `public IEnumerable<CupModel> Cups {get;set;}`.

Comment: I was working inside of the Home folder on accident. Double-check your folders.

Comment: @madreflection true that! nice spot.

Comment: I have 3 items in my DB, and I'm using @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.houseTitle to display the names for them. Instead of displaying the "houseTitle" I'm just displaying @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.houseTitle) again. Any solution?

Comment: Use @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.HouseTitle) for getting the contents of the property into the appropriate display field.